# The correct syntax of new line in html

Tags: html, syntax, cross-browser

I have seen so many different ways to break row in html.
I'm using `<br />` and it works fine.

What is the correct use of `<br />` as for now?

Comment: Read about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br

Comment: Background here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5 `certain elements are designated as having no end tag, for example <br>. These are collectively called void elements. The slash is just syntactic sugar for people who are addicted to XML.`

Answer (score 0):

`<br>` is correct way to implement for line break if you are using for address and paragraph purpose.